# html file not accessing variable in external javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm relatively new to javascript and I've run into the following issue which has been bugging me for a few hours now. I'm working with the following javascript and html file, but for some reason I can't seem to access the variables in test.js from ui.html

test.js

```
var ans;
 
function execShellCommand(cmd) {
    const exec = require('child_process').exec;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
       console.warn(error);
      }
      resolve(stdout? stdout : stderr);
     });
    });
   }

 async function myasyncfuntion() {  

   ans = await execShellCommand('sh diffcheck.sh');
   console.log(ans);
   
   }

   
myasyncfuntion();
```

ui.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    
  </head>
  <script>

     const diffString = ans;
     alert(diffString);

  </script> 
 
</html>
```

Can anyone explain to me why ans from test.js is not printed in the alert window when ui.html is run? And how can I fix it?

Comment: for one thing, your function is `async`, so even if your function worked, `ans` would still be undefined - see [this question and the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call). But more importantly, your code is using NodeJS features like `require`, and trying to execute shell commands - things which simply will not work when running in a browser.

Comment: The project I'm working on requires that I use the output from a shell command  to be printed on a browser. Is it not possible using javascript at all?

Comment: not running in the browser, no. That shell command has to run on some machine, and JS running in the browser runs on the client's machine - but can't execute arbitrary shell commands for very obvious reasons of security (imagine what a malicious website or script could do to an unsuspecting user's machine if that were possible!).

Comment: you could run a shell command with JS (or any other language) on the *server* and return the result of that to the front end to display to the user, if that was thought useful. I really don't know what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: You are most likely getting errors. Could you add those to your question?

Comment: Error: Command failed: sh diffcheck.sh

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:308:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1022:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:444:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:676:12) {
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'sh diffcheck.sh'
}
diff --git a/f3.txt b/f4.txt
index d90b8f1..f496a53 100644
--- a/f3.txt
+++ b/f4.txt
@@ -1,3 +1,2 @@
 hello world
-hello world world
-helo hello world
+hello hello

Comment: That's the output when I run test.js

Comment: that looks the output when you run it on your machine via the command line with node. Browsers do not know anything about nodejs, and you will get a very different output (full of errors) when it's run in the browser!

Comment: Yes, my browser output is simply an alert window with "undefined"